# Foundation 6 JS + React is not always working

Tags: reactjs, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I have an issue with foundation 6.4.1 and React I think.
My environment is configured as decribed here : [Foundation 6 + webpack : Cannot make Foundation JS work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276232/foundation-6-webpack-cannot-make-foundation-js-work)

I've added `$(document).foundation()`; inside my `index.js` in the `componentDidMount` method (I've tested at the top of the file, but it's not working)

```
componentDidMount() {
   $(document).foundation();
}
```

So with this configuration basically it's working, but after some route transition it stops working. In my case I'm logging out from the app and reconnect)

Where to use `$(document).foundation();` command for foundation to be working correctly ?

EDIT :
my index.js

```
/** @flow */
import 'babel-polyfill'

import 'script!jquery'
import 'script!what-input'
import 'foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.js'

import React from 'react'
import moment from 'moment'
...


const store = createStore()

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    initialized: false,
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      await store.dispatch(startLoggingInFromCookies())
      this.setState({ initialized: true })
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err)
    }

    $(document).foundation();
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.initialized) {
      return <Loader/>
    }

    return (
      <ReduxProvider store={store}>
        <RouterProvider>
          <div className="content">
            <Header/>
            {routes}
            <Footer/>
          </div>
        </RouterProvider>
      </ReduxProvider>
    )
  }
}

const mountPoint = document.getElementById('app')
render(<App/>, mountPoint)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you expand a little "but after some route transition it stops working"?

Comment: When I refresh the page it's working. When I log out (go to login page /login) then relogin ( going to "/") it's not working. the $(document).foundation(); is in the componentDidMount of the my index.js where I have my react-router component

Comment: I'm editing my question